# Tosca: Verify multiple possibilities in Tosca

Tags: tosca

I want to verify the Content of a box.
This box can have 2 good values out of 5 possible values and I want to look, whether the value in the box is one of the 2 good values.
How can I do it? How do I use the operator "OR"?

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to buffer the box content and then use an [Expression Evaluation](https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1520/en/content/standard_subset/automation_tools/expression_evaluation.htm) with `||`. I would imagine the expression evaluation would look something like `{B[Box Content]} == 'Value1' || {B[Box Content} == 'Value2'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex!
For Example the Value is 1 and you want to verify that the Value is 1,2,3,4 OR 5 then use the following syntax:

```
                          {REGEX[1|2|3|4|5]}
```